# Calling a TypeScript function from a Chart.js option callback

Tags: javascript, charts, typescript, angular, chart.js

I'm using a wrapper for Chart.js which allows for an animation callback to determine when the chart is done drawing.

So, my chart options look like this:

```
public chartOptions: any = {
    animation: {
        duration: 2000,
        onComplete: function () {
            //alert('anim complete');
            this.chartTestMethod();
        }
    },
    responsive: true
};
```

and my `chartTestMethod()` looks like this:

```
chartTestMethod() {
     console.log('chartTestMethod called.');
}
```

My hope is to have the method `chartTestMethod()` (which is in the same TypeScript file) called when the chart animation is complete. However, when the animation is complete and that method call line is executed, I get the error:

```
TypeError: this.chartTestMethod is not a function.
```

Basically, how can I call that method properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I imply that your **chartTestMethod** is in the same class as **chartOptions** since you're using it on **this**. You should make sure you understand how **this** is handled in JavaScript (and TypeScript being a superset of JavaScript). There must be a million references out there.

Without knowing anything about **Chart.js**, I think it is safe to assume that in no way the **this** context fits your class instance when **onComplete** is invoked. So what you want is an arrow function, like this:

```
onComplete: () => { this.chartTestMethod(); }
```

Read about TypeScript arrow function to understand how to make sure **this** is actually pointing to your instance.

Comment: Firstly, it doesn't solve OP's problem, because it is the same as defining function as an key of an object. Secondly, arrow function is not available in all ECMAScript versions.

Comment: The question is labelled "typescript" and unless the OP chooses a target supporting arrow functions it will be emulated using closure. In any case, using an arrow function "this" will point to the instance of whatever contains chartOptions.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. sgrtho's answer worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @sgrtho Then how can we access the data.datasets in `Chart.helpers.each(this.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, i)`  within oncomplete

Answer (score 1):

You got an error because `this` if referring to the object where function is executing. In your case, `this` is referring to `any.animation` object which do not have `chartTestMethod` key. You can solve it depending on where `chartTestMethod` is defined. If it is defined in global object, you can just remove `this` keyword. You can rewrite your code like this

```
function chartTestMethod(){
    console.log('chartTestMethod called.');
}

any = {
    animation: {
        duration: 2000,
        onComplete: function (){
            chartTestMethod();
        }
    },
    responsive: true
};
```

Also, if you want this method to be in the same object, you can do this

```
any = {
    animation: {
        duration: 2000,
        onComplete: function (){
            this.chartTestMethod();
        },
        chartTestMethod: function(){
            console.log('chartTestMethod called.');
      }
    },
    responsive: true
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use bind(this) 

public chartOptions: any = {
    animation: {
        duration: 2000,
        onComplete: function () {
            //alert('anim complete');
            this.chartTestMethod();
        }.bind(this)
    },
    responsive: true
};
```